# Ubuntu VG Missing On Boot, Can Recover with LiveCD. How to Edit Grub.conf?

Tags: linux, lvm, grub, initramfs

Running Ubuntu 20.04, I did what I thought was a simple apt update/upgrade (nvidia drivers) and then I rebooted.   I get the error:

Begin: waiting for root file system
lvm : error while loading shared libraries:
libdevmapper-event.so.1.02.1 cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
ALERT!   /dev/mapper ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv does not exist

and I'm at an initramfs prompt.  Trying "vgchange -ay" at the prompt fails with the same libdevmapper-event error.

I booted from livecd and ran vgchange -ay successfully, then mounted the partition successfully.  This is (obviously?) not persistent so if I reboot I end up back at the initramfs prompt.  The file libdevmapper-event.so.1.02.1 does exist in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdevmapper-event.so.1.02.1

Grub.cfg is accessible from the other partition, but right at the top it says "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE".   The vg UUID appears to be unchanged (seen via vgdisplay and compared with grub.cfg).   Is it possible to recover from this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you did it, but avoid as much as you can to download drivers on Linux like you would do on Windows (e.g. downloading a file from a website).

This, as you might now have understood, possibly hosed your Linux. Frankly, don't waste your time trying to repair it, just reinstall ubuntu.

One way to prevent such driver issues is to use your distro's non-free repository to install the latest Nvidia drivers from there, which in Ubuntu case are `restricted` and/or `multiverse` repositories.

Do note thatt Nvidia is infamously known to have bad drivers on Linux since they don't want to respect Linux standards, temper with open-source drivers for their GPUs (`nouveau`) and more.

The best GPUs to use on Linux are from AMD first, then Intel and finally nvidia's pre-Maxwell 2 (Maxwell 1 are GM-1xx based GPUs, such as GTX 750) GPUs, which are the exact opposite from what more recent nvidia's GPUs those are.
Since the aforementionned GPU's drivers are open source, they're often integreted on Linux isos which means you mostly won't need Linux post-installation... drivers installation.